# how to split a string using / and white space in java

Tags: java, arrays, split

My problem is I have a string like this

String text="UWU/CST/13/0032 F"

I want this to split by / and white spaces and put into a array.So finally the array indexes should include following
UWU,
CST,
13,
0032,
F

Comment: Please show your code so far, along with any problems you have - compiler errors, exception stack traces, and/or incorrect output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text.split("[/ ]")`, or `text.split("[/ ]", -1)` if you want trailing empty tokens to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `string.split(separator)` method that takes a String (regex expression) as an argument. Here is the documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

If you have:

```
String text = "UWU/CST/13/0032 F";
```

You can separate it by the white space first, splitting it into an array of two Strings, and then split the first String in the array by "/".

```
    String text = "UWU/CST/13/0032 F";

    String[] array = text.split(" ");
    String[] other = array[0].split("/");

    for (String e : array) System.out.println(e);
    for (String e : other) System.out.println(e);
```

This code outputs:

```
UWU/CST/13/0032
F
UWU
CST
13
0032
```

Comment: I think this is totally wrong. u should use "" not " "

Comment: @KickButtowski I just posted the full testing code and its output, which proves that it works. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: It doesn't work 'fine' in the sense that the result is split across two arrays unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can be used in Java to split Strings using the `String.split(String)` method.

For you particular situation, you should split the string on the regular expression `"(\s|/)"`. `\s` matches white space while `/` literally matches a forward slash.

The final code for this would be:

```
String[] splitString = text.split("(\\s|/)");
```

Comment: This also splits the string on the pipe character.

Comment: @AndyTurner My bad, the brackets need to be parentheses.